# How can I prevent players from placing blocks on an unmodded server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am working on making a vanilla Minecraft server but I want to prevent people from placing blocks at all. Is there any way?

Comment: Related (but not duplicate, since that one is narrower, requiring the solution to use Command Blocks): http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/124835/how-do-i-keep-players-from-placing-blocks-in-vanilla-minecraft

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it as a new question. Tacking your new question onto the end of another question doesn't work here. (I've removed the extra question from this post.)

Answer (score 5):

Put the player in Adventure Mode with the command `/gamemode <playername> a`

Comment: This will prevent them from breaking blocks only. If they manage to get any blocks (say, by picking up blocks broken by a creeper), they'll be able to place them.

Comment: Also, on that same point, if they manage to use these blocks to make tools, they can break blocks then. Though I forgot about that change to Adventure Mode completely.

Answer (score 5):

My answer in the linked question is a viable solution for this as well.

Modify the following variable in the server.properties file:

`spawn-protection=999999`

Then OP yourself and anyone else you trust to place and destroy blocks. There must be at least one OP for spawn-protection to work.

Comment: When you say "at least one OP" do you mean on the list of OPs or has to be logged in?

Comment: @Batophobia No, as http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Server.properties states: _If there are no ops **set** on the server, the spawn protection will be disabled automatically._ (emphasis mine) So you only need to have declared at least on OP, but they not need to be logged in

Comment: How can this be modified to let enderchests be opened?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: if you do /gamemode adventure @a, than none of the players can place or break blocks.

I hope this helped you

Answer (score -3):

Just turn Trust Players off. If you cannot, sorry!

Comment: Trust players is only for console systems, whether its playstation or xbox