# How to test if a player is near coordinates in 1.13?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I can't seem to figure this out. I am trying to testfor if a player is near certain coordiantes, namely {-9, 100, 16}, and then to teleport them somewhere else.

In earlier versions it would be `/testfor @a[x=-9,y=100,z=16,r=2]` in a repeating command block going into a chain conditional command block that says `/tp @p ~8 ~ ~`, although it seems in 1.13 they have removed /testfor. I've seen that apparently I'm supposed to use /execute now in some way but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/execute` already existed before and had most of the features it has now. But you don't even need that. Since you want to teleport relative to the command block, you can just use this:

```
/tp @a[x=-9,y=100,z=16,distance=..2] ~8 ~ ~
```

If you wanted to teleport the players 8 blocks from their location, you would use this:

```
execute as @a[x=-9,y=100,z=16,distance=..2] at @s run tp @s ~8 ~ ~
```

Comment: `r` also no longer exists, you'll need to use `distance`

Comment: That's right, corrected.

Comment: This does not work for me, any idea why? (Using Minecraft 1.13)

Comment: @Enrique You need to give way more details, in every way.

Comment: I just added the next command to my command block: ``execute as @a[x=x,y=y,z=z,distance=..2] at @s run say Hello`` Now, sorry if i didn't explain myself at the first time, english is not my native language. With a 2 Observers clock, my command block is able to execute this command over and over again and shows the message as soon as the user gets in the coordinates indicated by me. Either way, if I stay still, it will be executed forever. I need to do two things: keep watching those coordinates permanently and execute the command just a single time, never again. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Firstly, why don't you just use a repeating command block? It's easier and executed twice as fast. Secondly, your problem is different from his. He wants to teleport players away that enter the area, so spamming the output as long as they are inside is no problem, because they can't stay there. Your problem is a bit more complicated and the solution is here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/229652/is-there-a-way-to-set-an-adventure-mode-boundary-in-minecraft

Comment: @FabianRöling would the methods described in that post work for making sure that someone is looking a certain way when they spawn on a certain block? basically, i have a repeating command block that is set to teleport people who are on that block to their current location, just facing a direction i need them to face (since natural spawn is facing a different one). how would i do that so that they aren't stuck facing that direction every time they step on that specific block?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. So you want to rotate players a certain way when they stand on a block? And force them to always look there or not? I don't know what that has to do with the linked answer.