# Blocks keep reappearing in a certain area only

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

We had already recreated a world for the third time since we couldn't find any sea. And finally we found a place to make our home. But the blocks on about 15 x 15 area and about 30 blocks away from our house won't disappear.

Every time I destroy a block, it reappears as soon I destroy it. Our previous world doesn't have the same problem.

Comment: Adventure mode? Spawn protection? Lag?

Comment: @FabianRöling Adventure mode doesn't cause blocks to reappear when broekn,, but instead makes it impossible to break them in the first place

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a spawn protection problem. If all server members are trusted individuals, OP everyone and no one will have any problems. In some cases, deoping everyone can also remove the issue. If you are using plugins or mods, check the config files for that particular plugin or mod. Finally, I'm pretty sure the server owner is able to turn spawn protection off in the vanilla server config file.

**Edit:**
[This](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/124835/how-can-i-use-command-blocks-to-keep-players-from-placing-blocks-on-a-vanilla-se) question's top answer contains a description of how to *enable* spawn protection in a large portion of the world by setting the `spawn-protection` variable in the server.properties file to 999999. I assume that setting `spawn-protection=0` in server.properties would disable the effect entirely, and solve your problem.